# Generic customization of Publication Tasks web part

Tags: web-part

I have a Site Collection of type Enterprise Wiki with multiple subsites - each of which is created by custom code. I have a customized EnterpriseWiki.aspx that contains the UserTasksWebPart - so users can see their items from the "Workflow Tasks" list.

I now have the requirement to customize the columns of that web part, unfortunately the UserTasksWebPart is not customizable.

My first thought was to use the Content Query Editor Web Part, however, that requires me to specify a specific list by GUID, whereas the UserTasksWebPart simply references the local "Workflow Tasks" list. (technically, it runs a SPSiteDataQuery to get data from all lists with ServerTemplate="107" ...)

I'd prefer to avoid a solution using web services just for the sake of a better user experience.

I think the best solution is to create a custom web part that replicates the functionality of the UserTasksWebPart... is there a better approach? (Note that because these subsites are created in code any manual configuration of the individual subsite is not acceptable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using reflector to export the code of the UserTasksWebPart and then created my own web part, making the changes I required.